# Breeze fails on key fixup with custom code for adding entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, breeze

My company is updating the UI on an old product to bring it to modern browser compatibility and the like. One of the constraints we're working with is that we cannot change the database driving it. Unfortunately, the database is poorly formed and, as a result, we have to do some less-than-nice things to get this working.

One of the short-comings is that the process of adding, removing, updating, etc. data was all done through stored procedures. Since there are so many special cases and strange behaviors, it is not viable for us to get around them in the amount of time we have. Therefore, I'm trying to call these stored procedures when they are applicable. That much is working, but Breeze seems to be unhappy with what I'm doing.

More specifically, when going to add a particular entity, I land in the add method of a custom EF repository, call the stored procedure for adding, and set the state of the entity to unchanged. It gets added to the database and everything continues along fine until Breeze tries to fix the key from the temporary negative key it assigns to the new real one. Somehow, I need to tell Breeze what the new key is so it can resolve, but poking around in the docs for Breeze didn't get me anywhere. Any ideas? Below is the relevant code.

Context Provider:

```
protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
{

    foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, List<EntityInfo>> item in saveMap)
    {
        foreach (var entityItem in item.Value)
        {
            if (entityItem.Entity.GetType() == typeof (SerDevice))
            {
                var repo = new SerDeviceRepository(Context);
                var entity = entityItem.Entity as SerDevice;

                switch (entityItem.EntityState)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        repo.Add(entity);
                        break;
                }

                SetEntityState(entityItem, EntityState.Unchanged);
            }
        }
    }

    return base.BeforeSaveEntities(saveMap);
}
```

SerDeviceRepository:

```
public override void Add(SerDevice entity)
{
    var output =
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            "exec usp_Device_Add @p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5",
            entity.DeviceName, entity.IpAddress, entity.CommsId,
            entity.DeviceTypeId, entity.TemplateId, entity.DeviceStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this issue, this was the fix in my case.

In the ContextProvider, you can choose to override a method called `AfterSaveEntities` which does exactly what it sounds like it does. You get two parameters into this method: the save map and a list of key mappings. These key mappings indicate what the old temp key was and what the new real key is. Since I was preventing Entity Framework from doing its usual work by setting the entity's state to Unmodified, the key didn't get updated and when `AfterSaveEntities` gets called it has the temp key in the real key spot and `null` in the temp key spot.

The fix is simple. Just move the real key into the temp key spot (since it is actually the temp key) and retrieve the key of the item that was just added to the database from the `DbContext`. When the save finished and gets back to the client, Breeze will be none the wiser and will think Entity Framework took care of business as usual.

ExampleContextProvider.cs:

```
protected override void AfterSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap, List<KeyMapping> keyMappings)
{
    foreach (var item in saveMap)
    {
        foreach (var entityItem in item.Value)
        {
            if (entityItem.Entity.GetType() == typeof (Foo))
            {
                var entity = entityItem.Entity as Foo;

                foreach (var keyMapping in keyMappings)
                {
                    // Assuming your id is an int
                    if (entity != null && keyMapping.EntityTypeName == entity.GetType().ToString() && entity.Id < 0 && entity.Id == (int) keyMapping.RealValue)
                    {
                        // Get the new Foo from the database context
                        var foo = Context.Foos.First(f => f.FooName == entity.FooName);

                        // Move the temp to where it should be
                        // and get the real from the database
                        keyMapping.TempValue = keyMapping.RealValue;
                        keyMapping.RealValue = foo.Id;
                        entity.Id = foo.Id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    base.AfterSaveEntities(saveMap, keyMappings);
}
```

I hope this helps you if you had the same problem I did!

Comment: Thanks for this - I am running into the exact same problem with this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854113/how-to-save-data-with-a-view-and-stored-procedure-using-breeze/26872033#26872033. One thing I don't understand is this line:       var foo = Context.Foos.First(f => f.FooName == entity.FooName);   What value is this? Should it not be querying the Foos collection for the most recently added item? Only the ItemID is unique, so what is FooName?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out - I store a temp key mapping - very similar code - thanks for the lead                       //replace the temp
                    var tempKeyMapping = keyMappingsFixUp.Find(km => km.EntityTypeName == "Game" && (int) km.RealValue == game.GameId);
                    keyMapping.TempValue = tempKeyMapping.TempValue;
                    keyMapping.RealValue = mostRecentGame.GameId;
                    //delete this tempKeyMapping
                    keyMappingsFixUp.Remove(tempKeyMapping);