# How to save data with a View and stored procedure using Breeze

Tags: breeze

I am using BreezeJs on the server via WebAPI. I have inherited a 3rd party app which pulls data from a variety of lookup tables and custom field tables. To simplify things, I created a SQL View which pulls all the data together and gives them good column names. This Entity is called a "Game" and my mobile app uses Breeze on the client to get games. This all works fine.

I am unsure how to proceed when it comes to Saving.

I need to use the standard Breeze save syntax but on the server I assume something needs to intercept the Save method and run a custom stored procedure to save each column to the correct table.

So my question is: Am I on the right track on how to save entities with Views (not tables) and Breeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting makes perfect sense.  Take a look at the discussion of save interception here: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/contextprovider.

However, given that breeze can support your object graph directly. It might more sense to work with entities that are structured to be closer to your table structure and use breeze navigation properties to access related data.  You can still load your data in bulk via either anonymous projection queries that returns collections of entities ( good for lookup tables) or use the EntityQuery.extend method to look related data in a single pass.

Obviously, the decision about which way to go is dependent on the complexity and amount of additional code you need to write. But if you only have a few views then I might go with your suggested approach.  As the number of views grows, the alternative approach I've suggested may make more sense.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I understand now. The lookup tables are fairly simple, it is the Custom Field tables that add complexity - the data is in rows, not columns so it's quite a complicated view. Considering it is a small mobile app I will stick to this method for now.

Comment: Hi Jay, which event should I overwrite to do custom saving in my use-case above? This doc is very good - http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/contextprovider - however I am not sure exactly where to put the code - SaveChangesCore or BeforeSaveEntities? Basically I am getting an error message back like this "View or function 'dbo.SmartThinker_Framework_GameAds_C' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables." because I need to save it manually and then tell it not to save usin EF.

Comment: To clarify: I am looking at the NoDB sample and I can see how to save it when all save methods are NOT using an EF context. I am using an EF Context and want to use the standard SaveChanges method for everything except this 1 View DTO. When it is this entity, I need to save it manually and then tell it not to keep processing it. So my options seems to be: Put code in SaveChanges method in the Controller, Override BeforeSaveEntity, BeforeSaveEntities or SaveChangesCore (AfterSaveEntities seems too late). But once I have saved it, how do I tell it not to try and update the view using EF? Thanks

Comment: If you perform your 'custom' save logic in BeforeSaveEntities, simply remove the view entities from the saveMap before returning.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks, so by removing them from the map they will not be processed further...   however, I do want the normal Breeze process to kick in after saving - ie. the modified entities should be returned down to the client. However, I will get the save saving first and then worry about sending it back to the client later.

Answer (score 1):

You've abstracted away the complexity of reading the game data using a view, now all you need to do is abstract away the writing of the data (create/update/delete) using `instead of` triggers.  This approach will make your view behave just like a table so your application code can forget that it's a view altogether and simply treat it like any other table.

[TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx):

> The primary advantage of INSTEAD OF triggers is that they enable views
>   that would not be updatable to support updates. A view based on
>   multiple base tables must use an INSTEAD OF trigger to support
>   inserts, updates, and deletes that reference data in more than one
>   table.

Comment: Hmm - I am not aware of this method - I will investigate, thanks

Comment: If you share your view sql we might be able to help with the triggers

Comment: Hi Jeremy - I understand more about what you are proposing - http://www.writebetterbits.com/2007/12/using-instead-of-trigger-in-sql-server.html :  it is different way to accomplish the same thing but using DB code instead of Breeze or C#... very interesting. At this stage I would rather use Breeze and C#, however it is good to know this option!

Comment: I wonder if this approach would also work:  http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx   Map stored procs to the View Entity... i'll have to try it